# How to use an ObjectDataProvider to bind an enum to a ComboBox in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, objectdataprovider

I am trying to bind an `Enum` to a `ComboBox`. I have seen a lot of people using an `ObjectDataProvider` but I cannot seem to access it. I have also noticed that some people are using it within a `Window.Resources`, rather than `Page.Resources` but I cannot find how it is used on `Page.Resources`. I have been searching for a solution for hours.

What I have so far:

**XAML**

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sports;assembly=Sports"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ViewModel="using:Sports.ViewModel"
xmlns:model="using:Sports.Model"
xmlns:system="using:System"


x:Class="Sports.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:CreateSubsVM/>
</Page.DataContext>
    <Page.Resources>

    <ObjectDataProvider></ObjectDataProvider>
    </Page.Resources>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

**C#**

```
public enum SubsAmount
{
    [Display(Description = "One Year")]
    Oneyear = 0,
    [Display(Description = "Two Years")]
    TwoYears = 1,
    [Display(Description = "Three Years")]
    ThreeYears = 2
}


public class ComboboxConverter: IValueConverter
{

    public string GetEnumValues(Enum enumObj)
    {
        DisplayAttribute attribute = enumObj.GetType().
        GetRuntimeField(enumObj.ToString()).
        GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SubsAmount), false).
        SingleOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute;
        return attribute == null ? enumObj.ToString() : attribute.Description;
    }


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return GetEnumValues((Enum) value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return Enum.ToObject(targetType, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear on how you're actually calling the converter. Just how much code did you leave out?

Comment: _"I cannot seem to access it"_ -- what does that mean? The code you show above cannot successfully use `ObjectDataProvider` because you've declared it using an empty element. It only works when you provide the necessary values. Done correctly, it will work fine. Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a _precise_ description of what went wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example with a page object(according to the MSDN [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) there is no any restriction to use the ObjectDataProvider  with page):

**Update #1**

**Xaml**

```
<Page x:Class="PageBasedApp.MyPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:pageBasedApp="clr-namespace:PageBasedApp"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
Title="MyPage">
<Page.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Gestures" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type ApplicationGesture}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="ApplicationGesture" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="SubAmounts" MethodName="GetShortListOfApplicationGestures" ObjectType="{x:Type pageBasedApp:DisplayAttributeBasedObjectDataProvider}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="pageBasedApp:SubsAmount" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <Label Content="All Gestures:"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Gestures}}" Width="150"/>
        <Label Content="Sub Amounts:"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SubAmounts}}" Width="150"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Here is a custom Data provider code**

```
public class DisplayAttributeBasedObjectDataProvider : ObjectDataProvider
{
    public object GetEnumValues(Enum enumObj)
    {
        var attribute = enumObj.GetType().GetRuntimeField(enumObj.ToString()).
            GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false).
            SingleOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute;
        return attribute == null ? enumObj.ToString() : attribute.Description;
    }

    public List<object> GetShortListOfApplicationGestures(Type type)
    {
        var shortListOfApplicationGestures = Enum.GetValues(type).OfType<Enum>().Select(GetEnumValues).ToList();
        return
            shortListOfApplicationGestures;
    }
}
```

**Attribute code and enum:**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DisplayAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DisplayAttribute(string displayName)
    {
        Description = displayName;
    }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public enum SubsAmount
{
    [Display("One Year")]
    Oneyear = 0,
    [Display("Two Years")]
    TwoYears = 1,
    [Display("Three Years")]
    ThreeYears = 2
}
```

**How it looks like:**
[image: here.]

P.S. You don't need any converters here.
Regards.

Comment: @andas1951 please see the updated version, here I've used the Display attribute as you tried.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation :)!

Comment: feel free to mark this as answered, in case it was helpful.